# how to integrate hogan.js code inside flask template?

Tags: flask, hogan.js

As suggested i m tring to write hogan.js code inside .html file which located in templates folder of flask structure. when i execute python file, index page render with bellow error

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError
TemplateSyntaxError: unexpected char u'#' at 36667
```

i have also attached part of index.html code bellow.

```
<div class="cell link">
    <a href="{{url}}"> >> view {{type}} details</a>
    {{#console_id}}
    <a href="/project/instances/{{console_id}}/vnc" class="vnc_window">» open console</a>
    {{/console_id}}
</div>
```

python file code

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

i also included hogan.js file

```
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='horizon/lib/hogan-2.0.0.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

please help me to figure out this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try escaping hogan tags like this:

```
{{ '{{#console_id}}' }}
```

Otherwise flask treats it as a part of jinja template and tries to evaluate expression inside curly braces.

If you want to avoid autoescaping you can use `safe` filter.

```
 {{ '{{> table1}}' | safe }}
```

Comment: thnx.. its work perfectly.! but i got another prb. i have bellow code {{'{{> table1}}'}} which is not working correctly bcoz it convert into {{&gt; table1}}. can you tell me how to prevent this conversation ?

Comment: i got it. . need to use {% autoescape false %} {{'{{> table1}}'}} {% endautoescape %}